# How to show transparent camera icon like on a facebook profile picture

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a `react app`. Which allows the user to set their profile picture. I want to set the layout so when the user hovers over the profile picture it shows a transparent button like it is shown in Facebook'` profile picture.

Here is what I have Done

```
 let cur_image = ''
        //if user has selected any image
        if (this.state.image) {
            //show image
            cur_image =
                <div>
                    <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: '50%' }}>
                        <img
                            src={this.state.image}
                            alt="Your Profile"
                            style={{ width: "150px", height: "150px" }}
                        />
                    </button>
                </div>
        } else {
            //show camera Icon
            cur_image = <IconButton component="span"><CameraAlt style={{ width: "150px", height: "150px" }} /></IconButton>
        }
```

I have tried doing it with CSS properties like height and width but I have no idea what to do after that. I did not get any error but have no idea what properties I can use and why?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far, so we can help you out.

Comment: Basically i have nothing that can be shown as code because i have not tried anything except height and width properties as I do not know which other properties should be used. All I want is a picture which has a transparent button like the one in facebook

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just to give a way how to proceed with it.

```css
.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://icon-library.net/images/avatar-icon-free/avatar-icon-free-10.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.icon-layer {
  display: none;
  background: #80808069;
 }

.background:hover > .icon-layer {
    display: block;
}


img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="icon-layer">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2-7/66/97-512.png"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```